# Difference between genkey and selfcert

Tags: ssl-certificate, public-key-encryption, keytool

Can somebody please explain me the difference between keytool command genkey and selfcert, where I googled and I got both will generate self signed certificate, whats the difference then ?

How can I sign a CSR with a certificate using keytool command ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

genkey creates both a key and a cert.  selfcert replaces the cert for an existing key with a new self-cert.  Do this when your old cert has expired.  If you want to sign it with a different cert (maybe from a CA) use import.

Answer (score 0):

I will first assume that you have generated the CSR and sent it across to a CA. The CA returns back the certificate that you can `importcert` back into the keystore for the same `alias` for which you generated the CSR.

So in short:

`keytool -v -importcert -keystore mykeystore.jks -alias mycertalias -file CASignedCert.cer -trustcacerts`